# How to search hash_map containing reference_wrapper?

Tags: c++, hashmap, tbb

I'm using Intel TBB [Concurrent Hash Map](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_hash_map_cls.htm) `tbb::hash_map<std::string, std::reference_wrapper<Clusters>>` and I want to search this hash_map using

```
tbb::concurrent_hash_map<std::string, std::reference_wrapper<Clusters>>::accessor a;
if(table.find(a, operation.get().GetKey()))
{
    a->second.get().AddOperation(operation);
}
```

But it gives `error: no matching function for call to ‘std::reference_wrapper<Clusters>::reference_wrapper()`. So the problem is `reference_wrapper` has no default constructor which `find` needs. Is there any way I can circumvent this?

Comment: There is no `std::hash_map`, and `std::unordered_map` has no member named `accessor`. Are these from some library?

Comment: Sorry, I thought std hash_map has the same members. It's from Intel TBB concurrent hash map

Comment: Is the error reported from `find()`? It doesn't seem to need such a constructor. Can you show the implementation of `GetKey()`?

Comment: `ParallelClusterCreator.h:27:54:   required from here
/usr/include/tbb/concurrent_hash_map.h:589:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::reference_wrapper<Clusters>::reference_wrapper()’ this is whole error message.
`

Comment: `GetKey` is simple `std::string GetKey() const { return key; }`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a bug in the implementation of `find()` or its documentation. Either it needs the mapped type to be `DefaultConstructible` when it shouldn't, or it doesn't document that it needs this.

I don't think this is something you can fix. As a workaround, you could store pointers in the map instead of reference wrappers.